# downloading data vba run time error 5

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Download()

Dim fromCurr As String, endDate As String, str As String

fromCurr = Sheets("Currencies").Range("fromCurr").Value
endDate = Sheets("Currencies").Range("endDate").Value

Sheets("Data").Cells.Clear

str = "http://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=" _
    & fromCurr _
    & "&date=" _
    & Year(endDate) & "-" & Month(endDate) & "-" & Day(endDate)


    With Sheets("Data").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;" & str, Destination _
    :=Range("$D$3"))
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebTables = """historicalRateTbl"""
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    End Sub
```

I'm trying to download currency data from a website given the specified currency and the data. (From this site http://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=DKK&date=2017-04-18)

Whenever I run my macro, I get Run-time Error 5.

Comment: Invalid procedure call or argument. At what line do you get this error?

Comment: fromCurr = Sheets("Currencies").Range("fromCurr").Value
endDate = Sheets("Currencies").Range("endDate").Value
You have declarations that depend on themselves, I won't be surprised if this is the part that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your date format to force two-digit month and day and got rid of the ActiveSheet parent of Range("D3"). This works for me with =TODAY() in Range("endDate").

```
Option Explicit

Sub Download()

    Dim fromCurr As String, endDate As Long, str As String

    fromCurr = Worksheets("Currencies").Range("fromCurr").Value
    endDate = Worksheets("Currencies").Range("endDate").Value

    Worksheets("Data").Cells.Clear

    str = "http://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=" _
        & fromCurr _
        & "&date=" _
        & Format(endDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    Debug.Print str

    With Worksheets("Data")
        With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & str, Destination:=.Range("D3"))
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .WebTables = """historicalRateTbl"""
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```